# Data Structure choices based on requirements

Tags: java, data-structures

I'm completely new to programming and to java in particular and I am trying to determine which data structure to use for a specific situation. Since I'm not familiar with Data Structures in general, I have no idea what structure does what and what the limitations are with each.

So I have a CSV file with a bunch of items on it, lets say Characters and matching Numbers. So my list looks like this:

A,1,B,2,B,3,C,4,D,5,E,6,E,7,E,8,E,9,F,10......etc.

I need to be able to read this in, and then:

1)display just the letters or just the numbers sorted alphabetically or numerically

2)search to see if an element is contained in either list.

3)search to see if an element pair (for example A - 1 or B-10) is contained in the matching list.

Think of it as an excel spreadsheet with two columns. I need to be able to sort by either column while maintaining the relationship and I need to be able to do an IF column A = some variable AND the corresponding column B contains some other variable, then do such and such.

I need to also be able to insert a pair into the original list at any location. So insert A into list 1 and insert 10 into list 2 but make sure they retain the relationship A-10.

I hope this makes sense and thank you for any help! I am working on purchasing a Data Structures in Java book to work through and trying to sign up for the class at our local college but its only offered every spring...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use two sorted [Maps](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) such as [TreeMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html).
One would map Characters to numbers (`Map<Character,Number>` or something similar). The other would perform the reverse mapping (`Map<Number, Character>`)

Let's look at your requirements:

> 1)display just the letters or just the numbers sorted alphabetically
>   or numerically

Just iterate over one of the maps. The iteration will be ordered.

> 2)search to see if an element is contained in either list.

Just check the corresponding map. Looking for a number? Check the `Map` whose keys are numbers.

> 3)search to see if an element pair (for example A - 1 or B-10) is
>   contained in the matching list.

Just `get()` the value for `A` from the Character map, and check whether that value is `10`. If so, then A-10 exists. If there's no value, or the value is not 10, then A-10 doesn't exist.

When adding or removing elements you'd need to take care to modify both maps to keep them in sync.

Comment: thanks! How do I get the key from the Character Map?

Comment: Thank you! I've got it (for the most part). I'm loading the values into two TreeMaps, then I can convert them to Collections assign an iterator and then iterate over them to display (although this isnt sorted alphabetically but by the key assigned).